# Is there a extended FirstBetween method for C# List<T>?

Tags: c#, .net

I want a generic method to find the first position(we can treat a index as position) which a given data is great than the one and less than the next one.

For example, I have an int list[12,34,4,65], if I give a number 15(which is great than 12 and less than 34) it should return 1, if I give a number 50 it should return 3, etc.

this is what i wrote, but I feel there must be an easier way:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static int FirstBetween<T>(this List<T> list, T t)
    {
        if (list == null)
            return -1;
        if(t == null)
            return -1;
        if(list.Count == 0 )
            return 0;

        T item1;
        for(int index = 0;index<list.Count;index++)
        {
            T item2 = list[index];
            if(IsBetween(item1,item2,t))
                return index;

            item1 = item2;            
        }          
        return list.Count;  
    }

    private static bool IsBetween<T>(T t1, T t2, T t)
    {
        if (t1 == null && t2 == null)
            return false;
        else if(t1==null && t<=t2)//in case of the first item
            return true;
        else if (t2 == null && t >= t1)//in case of the last item
            return true;
        else if(t>=t1 && t<=t2)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

This is unfinished code and I feel this is too complicated,and as a template method it still has some the other problems.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: 1) What have you tried? 2) It seems quite inconsistent.

Comment: Doesn't sound too hard, can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: I have to iterate the list and use compare to find the result.I am wondering if there is a easy way to do it.

Comment: @Giswin: You seem to have a basic understanding as to what is necessary from a high level. Show a sample of code that attempts the problem, and comparing its output to what you expect.

Comment: Showing your sample code could also illuminate what you do when an input number is >= one number or <= the next (because I am curious about that).  Also since you want position number, your own examples should return 0 instead of 1, and 2 instead of 3 because their positions are 0-based.

Comment: The name `FirstBetween` sounds like it should return an item from the list, rather than the index.  Also, consider throwing an `ArgumentNullException` instead of returning an invalid value if `null` is passed in.  Your code is incomplete, fix the bugs and it looks fine.

Comment: I will post my code later when it works, thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: @Giswin Take a look at my sample

Comment: You say you will post your code later when it works; what will your question be then? And what is your question in the meantime? This doesn't seem like a well-formed request...

Comment: where is `item1` initialized?

Answer (score 3):

Using IComparable constraint for the generic type should do the trick:

```
  public static int FirstBetween<T>( this List<T> list, T value) where T:IComparable<T> {
        if (list == null || value == null) return -1;

        for (int index = 1; index < list.Count; index++) {
            if (( list[index - 1].CompareTo( value ) < 0 ) 
                  && list[index].CompareTo( value ) > 0)
                return index;
        }
        return list.Count;
    }
```

Optimized version but less readable, still not checking null items in list, what makes things a little uglier:

```
    public static int FirstBetween<T>( this List<T> list, T value) where T:IComparable<T> {
        if (list == null && value == null) return -1;
        if (list.Count == 0) return 0;
        var last = value.CompareTo( list[0] );
        for (int index = 1; index < list.Count; index++) {
            if (( last > 0 ) &&  (last = value.CompareTo(list[index] )) < 0)
                return index;
        }
        return list.Count;
    }
```

Comment: +1 I think that's it, at least the idea. This code could be optimized to avoid comparing `value` with each array item twice. Also one should be careful that some list items may be null, so you'd better do the comparison the other way round: `value.CompareTo(list[index])`.

Comment: @jods you are right but optimization is evil :P I think that comparing twice can't be avoided because the list is not ordered...

Comment: @Blau *Premature* optimization is the root of all evil, as the saying goes.  That's not to say that all optimization is evil.  Also note several of the comments listed were optimizing the correctness, not the speed.  Adding code to handle things like null values is important, and most certainly not evil.

Comment: @Blau The list doesn't have to be ordered: you need the result of the previous comparison and the current one, that's all. It's pretty easy actually.

Comment: @jods yep, saving the value is enough

Answer (score 0):

```
private int? returnIndex(int val = 15)
        {
            List<int> myList = new List<int>() { 12, 34, 4, 65 };
            int listCount = myList.Count;
            int? position = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < listCount; i++)
            {
                var currPosition = myList[i];
                if (i + 1 >= listCount)
                {
                    position = i;
                    break;
                }
                var nextPosition = myList[i + 1];
                if (val >= currPosition && val <= nextPosition)
                {
                   position = i +1;
                   break;
                 }
            }
            return position;
        }
```

Comment: That's a really weird and not optimized code. Why do you have a `continue` at the end of the `for`?

Comment: It should be just the break, I miss typed. Going to edit.
The answer got down voted just because a miss continue?

Comment: No, I downvoted because you access the array twice for each element and your code is not really readable.

Comment: You are right, this is not the best aproach for iterating this array, but I beliave that wouldn't bring any problem, considering memory and speed.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static int? FirstBetween<T>(this List<T> list, T val) where T : IComparable
    {
        if (list != null && !ReferenceEquals(val, null))
        {
            bool greater = false;
            for (int i = 1; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                var lastGreater = i == 1 ? (list[i-1].CompareTo(val) > 0) : greater;
                greater = list[i].CompareTo(val) > 0;
                if (!lastGreater && greater)
                    return i;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```